# Nested transactions are not allowed in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, genymotion

I am working on an android app and I am using realm DB, my app was worked properly, but suddenly if i want to write to DB the app stopped and give me this error.

```
Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
---
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nested transactions are not allowed. Use
commitTransaction() after each beginTransaction().
atio.realm.internal.ImplicitTransaction.promoteToWrite(ImplicitTransaction.java:)
 at io.realm.Realm.beginTransaction(Realm.java:1454)
at.onClick(AddMedication.java:52)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method
com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
```

I tried many available solutions but the problem have not fixed yet!

any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are calling beginTransaction() twice. Before the second call you must commit or rollback the first one.

```
beginTransaction(); // First call
try{
  doSomeWorkOnDB();
  commit();
} except (...){
  rollback();
}
...
beginTransaction(); // Second call
try{
  doOtherWorkOnDB();
  commit();
} except (...){
  rollback();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: r.beginTransaction();
r.copyToRealmOrUpdate(medication);
r.commitTransaction();
  this what i used and it doesn't loop or if..
  i am just want to copy data from object to realm object.

Comment: Are you calling beginTransaction() inside copyToRealmOrUpdate() method?

Comment: No I did not, it just build in method I use it.

Comment: So, probably copyToRealmOrUpdate(medication) open its own transaction. Just dont start one yourself and it will work fine.

Comment: You welcome. If you find it helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.